# Close Token Account With Multiple Destinations

Tags: spl-token, anchor-spl

Is it possible to call close_account function by providing multiple destinations? If so, how do I do it. Otherwise, is using a proxy account as a destination which will send the rent money to multiple accounts a good approach?

Comment: do you want to do this via client or contract code? the operation will be basically the same, but any code examples provided will be different

Comment: new question -> new post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close an account and distribute the remaining SOL (including the rent exempt balance) to multiple destination accounts.  You simply subtract the remaining SOL in the account and add the sum total of that same amount to N other accounts.  So for example, if there is 1 SOL left in the account (including rent exempt reserve), then you could distribute it to 5 other accounts equally by subtracting 1 SOL from the account to debit and adding 0.2 SOL to each of the accounts to credit.

The above would have to be accomplished by a custom program because there is no existing program that does this.